# How safe is cross domain access?

Tags: cross-domain

I am working on a personal project and I have being considering the security of sensitive data. I want to use API for accessing the Backend and I want to keep the Backend in a different server from the one the user will logon to. This then require a cross domain accessing of data.

Considering that a lot of accessing and transaction will be done, I have the following questions to help guide me in the right path by those who have tried and tested cross domain access. I don't want to assume and implement and run into troubles and redesign when I have launched the service thereby losing sleep. I know there is no right way to do many things in programming but there are so many wrong ways.

1. How safe is it in handling sensitive data (even with https).
2. Does it have issues handling a lot of users transactions.
3. Does it have any downside I not mentioned.

These questions are asked because some post I have read this evening discouraged the use of cross-domain access while some encouraged it. I decided to hear from professionals who have actually used it in a bigger scale.

I am actually building a Mobile App, using Laravel as the backend.

Thanks..

Comment: Wait, what does this had to do with jquery..?

Comment: You can send ajax requests without jquery as well... BTW, this question isn't about sending ajax requests using jquery... Why should you ask jquery experts regarding cross domain security.. jquery is just a javascrit library...

Comment: My bad, I got it wrong then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How safe is it in handling sensitive data (even with https).

SSL is generally considered safe (it's used everywhere and is considered the standard). However, it's not any less safe by hitting a different server. The data still has to traverse the pipes and reach its destination which has the same risks regardless of the server.

> Does it have issues handling a lot of users transactions.

I don't see why it would. A server is a server. Ultimately, your server's ability to handle volume transactions is going to be based on its power, the efficiency of your code, and your application's ability to scale.

> Does it have any downside I not mentioned.

Authentication is the only thing that comes to mind. I'm confused by your question as to how they would log into one but access data from another. It seems that would all just be one application. If you want to revise your question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bad practice but I want users to logon on a particular server but get data from another. The second server is where the data will be stored. For example, the app users will logon to the second server but there are some set of users that will be using the report produced by the App users on the second server.

Comment: How will you authenticate them?

Comment: During registration, I plan to copy the authentication data to both servers and then access via an API. I just want the files (php) to be in the first server.

Comment: Interesting. Make sure your connections originating from one server going to the next are encrypted as well.

Comment: Thanks... I can now go ahead with implementation then

Comment: Sure. Based on the little I know, there is probably a better way to do what you're wanting to accomplish, but, it's out of the scope of this question. I'd research service oriented architecture for a more in-depth look at what you're doing. Security wise, just make sure everything is encrypted and the separate server part is a non-issue.